# Does the surface of austenitic steels have an especially "dynamic" phase somewhere between 100 and 200 Celsius?

Tags: temperature, material-science

There is lots of kitchen lore about pans. One popular concept are the "pores" of a steel pan surface, which are the reason why food sticks to the pan when it's not heated properly.

I don't know much about material science, but I know that the "pores" are not real pores, but irregular gaps or even cracks. The simple theory about them goes that they close when the pan expands under heat, so the surface gets more even.

But I recently saw a different theory, which asserts that in a not-sufficiently heated pan, the "pores" are somehow moving, but once the pan is heated, they are "static". This surprised me, as I assume that the steel continues to expand while getting even hotter.

So, is this claim of "static pores" true or not? Do they move more up to the point of proper heating, and stop afterwards? Or is the second theory a bad way to express the first one? Or just plain incorrect?

Assume that the pan is made of 300 series steel, most probably 18/10, and the low boundary of "properly heated" is somewhere between 150 and 180 Celsius. So with some generous rounding, we can assume that a slightly hot pan (100 Celsius and above) sticks, but has stopped sticking at 200 Celsius at the latest.

Here is a video with a dumbed down explanation of the pore theory, the second one embedded in the article: http://www.houseboateats.com/2009/12/on-properly-heating-your-pan.html.

Comment: The simple and concise answer to your question involves a used steel pan sample and a scanning electron microscope rigged with a heated probe holder. I think it might be worth doing the experiment.

Comment: from a material science point of view , No. There arent any phases that is formed at 100-200 C. there is phase transformation only above 600 C(approximately) i think.